# Why doesn't Chrome Dev Tools auto-include the parenthesis when selecting a method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

If you are in the console of Dev Tools, and you have an object, lets say `x`, and it has three methods/functions, let's say `a()`, `b()`, and `c(i, j, k)`, why doesn't it auto insert the parens, let alone the parens with the correct spaces for the parameters (like eclipse for java) when you use the auto-complete tab or enter?

It currently will only print once selected `x.a`, `x.b`, or `x.c` without the function parens.

I'm assuming that it doesn't know about the parameters because it is JS, and in Java, you can only call a constructor of a fixed order and types, where JS can be overloaded, and error out, but Im just wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why DevTools should assume that I would call a method from autocomplete. Maybe I want to add another `.` after the method name and see all these `apply`, `bind`, `call`, `name` etc. methods and properties that I can call? What I mean, is that `someObject.someMethod()` is not the end of the road in JavaScript.

[image: Picture of the nested methods]

Answer (score 1):

there is no guarantee that function wants to see only one parameter even if it was declared as a function with one argument because the function could use arguments local variable.

```
function func(a,b) {
  alert(arguments[0])
  alert(arguments[1])
  alert(arguments[2])
}


func(1,2,3)
```

Also sometimes you could just pass the function as a callback.